# error while loading route, cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, single-page-application

I am trying to load the `/bookmarks` page.

When I click `{{#link-to 'bookmarks'}}Bookmarks{{/link-to}}` I get the error:

`Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

I have a bookmark model:

```
App.Bookmark = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});
```

bookmarks route:

```
App.BookmarksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
      return this.store.find('bookmark');
    }
});
```

router;

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('bookmarks', function(){
        this.route('new');
    });
});
```

bookmarks controller:

```
App.BookmarksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

bookmarks template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bookmarks">
    <h2>All my bookmarks</h2>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>URL</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each controller}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{title}}</td>
            <td>{{url}}</td>
          </tr>

        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>

    {{#linkTo 'bookmarks.new'}}New bookmark{{/linkTo}}

    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you using the RESTAdapter? Can you show the payload returned by the server?

Comment: No I'm using the local storage adapter `App.Store = DS.LSAdapter;`

Comment: I think your adapter declaration is wrong, give a look in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your adapter like the following:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter;
```